# How to control apache service on OS X (start/stop/restart/graceful restart)?

Tags: apache, launchd

I have Apache installed on OS X and I want to know what command I can use to:

- start apache
- stop apache
- restart apache
- gracefully restart apache

Also I want to know if the commands were successful or not.

Apache seams to be installed as `org.apache.httpd` or at least this is what `sudo launchctl list|grep apache` shows.

Comment: Not sure why but `launchctl stop org.apache.httpd` doesn't do anything but `service stop org.apache.httpd` seems to work even if it does warn me that I should use launchctl instead.

Comment: If your apache has launchd configuration files, then you would have to load and unload the `org.apache.httpd` to affect launchd control over the app. Are you using the built in apache or installing it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

I use the `apachectl` command

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo apachectl start
sudo apachectl restart
sudo apachectl -k graceful
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't work on Lion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065288/how-to-remove-autostart-of-apache-on-macosx